# Default value of checkbox in Symfony

Tags: symfony

If the checkbox is selected, does the variable take the value 1, and if not selected the value 0?

```
$builder
    ->add('happy', 'checkbox', array(
        'label' => 'Are you happy?',
        'data' => false,
    ));
```

In this link, it is not clear to me:

> The value that's actually used as the value for the checkbox or radio button. This does not affect the value that's set on your object.
>
> https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Are you asking about the "wording" of the "value" description? It seems you might have 2 questions here.

Comment: I was talking about the value saved in the data base. I looked up in the SQL database, and I saw that when the checkbox is selected, the value 1.0000 is saved, as I thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$builder
      ->add('happy', 'checkbox', array(
      'label'=>'Are you happy?',
      'data'=>false,
      'attr' => array('checked' => 'checked', 'value' => '1')
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the return value on form submission? Going by the linked page, it looks like it should return a boolean:

`if the box is checked -> the field will be set to true;`
`if the box is unchecked -> the value will be set to false.`

To be sure, you could always try dumping out the result of

```
$form->getData();
```